Routing between two interfaces
I have a linux Debian 12 machine hosted on a virtual machine (linode).
It has two physical interfaces:
eth0 - WAN - with access to www - not relevant for the question.
eth1 - LAN - Manually configured with a static ip address 10.99.0.1/24.
Then i have another virtual interface
wg1 - LAN - Manually configured with a static ip address 10.97.0.1/24
eth1 is used as the endpoint for all VPN connections towards site-to-site <> clients.
using ipsec proto.
wg1 is used as the endpoint for all VPN connections used for employees,
using wireguard vpn.
The VPNs are working fine:
Site-to-site, the tunnels are up and I can ping from the server all sites .1 ip address.
Employee vpn, the employee has the VPN installed on its PC. The tunnel is up and can ping the server.
To keep thing straight forward the firewall is disabled for testing reasons - to discard the possibility that simply the firewall is blocking.
IPV4 Forwarding is Enabled by editing the file /etc/sysctl.conf
and setting attributes to net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

The problem is actually achieving "connecting" between the employee PC to the remote sites.
SERVER SIDE
root@be1:~#ip a
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 90:de:01:af:97:36 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.99.0.1/24 brd 10.99.0.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::92de:1ff:feaf:9736/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: wg1: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1420 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/none
    inet 10.97.0.1/24 scope global wg1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
       
root@be1:~#ip route
10.97.0.0/24 dev wg1 proto kernel scope link src 10.97.0.1
10.99.0.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.99.0.1

EMPLOYEE PC
C:\Users\4lele>ipconfig

Unknown adapter BE1:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.97.0.11
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :


C:\Users\4lele>route print -4
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
        10.97.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.97.0.11      5
       10.97.0.11  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.97.0.11    261
        10.99.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.97.0.11      5
       10.100.0.0      255.255.0.0         On-link        10.97.0.11      5
      10.100.14.0    255.255.255.0         On-link        10.97.0.11      5
    10.100.14.255  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.97.0.11    261
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

C:\Users\4lele>ping 10.99.0.1

Pinging 10.99.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.99.0.1: bytes=32 time=17ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.99.0.1: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.99.0.1: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.99.0.1: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 10.99.0.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 16ms, Maximum = 17ms, Average = 16ms

C:\Users\4lele>ping 10.100.14.1

Pinging 10.100.14.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 10.100.14.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),

Is it well designed? Maybe there's something fundamental that needs to be corrected which I am not aware of... please point out if so.
If there's anything else, information please comment and i will reply.
Regards,
Ale.

It's not really clear how your server is currently routing to the 10.100.x.y networks. Do your server and clients have routes for all those networks like 10.100.14.0/24? And do the remote sites have a route back to the 10.97.0.0 network?

Dear @Cpt.Whale,
On the Debian server I am using strongSwan to create the tunnels between remote routers to the server using IPsec protocol.
The server side advertises which other networks (10.99.0.1/24) should be injected to the routing table of the other side (the router\s).
On the router I declare which subnets (10.100.14.1/24) it advertises and injects to the routing table on the server side.
When I look up for the routing tables in the router, I see it knows it route to reach the server.

It sounds like you'll need to advertise 10.97.0.0/24 via 10.99.0.1 on the router side, and add routes for each 10.100.x.y network to your clients so they know to send that traffic through the vpn. It might be helpful to do a network trace on your server's eth1 interface to see if wg client traffic is getting forwarded through it

There's another important configuration option: net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter
Let me quote the short description:

"(...)with rp_filter set to true if the reply to a packet wouldn't go
out the interface this packet came in, then this is a bogus packet and
should be ignored"

Also note, that per-interface configuration of rp_filter takes precedence, meaning that with rp_filter globally turned off net.ipv4.conf.<INTERFACE_NAME>.rp_filter=1 will prevent packets received by <INTERFACE_NAME> to be replied through any other interface.

Tried your suggestion and it did not help.
Whatmore, i don't have eth0.

@AlejandroLichtenfeld edited my answer a little, now it should be easier to implement :)
